# App Engine log console severely lagging behind

Tags: google-app-engine

For a few days now, my App Engine logging console has been behind for a steady 2-5 hours. That is, any logging messages appear in the console over 2 hours after they've been generated.

Sadly, there are parts of the application I can not test locally (OAuth-style callbacks, etc). All apps are written in Python.

Has *anyone* ever had this kind of problem? Any solutions, workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the timezone setting, [reported by many](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5494&can=5&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log).

Comment: Still not fixed ... yeesh. This caused me so much pain yesterday. Btw, if you leave it on the default PST timezone it's fine.